# Why don't my questions get views? I asked 15 questions on my account, but only 6 questions have been answered

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, views

Why don't my questions get views? I asked 15 questions on my account but only 6 questions have been answered. Is access to my questions restricted? Why?

I don't know what is going on regarding my account on SO, even though I have not got any notifications whether there is a problem or not with my questions.

Comment: 6 out of 15 questions answered is pretty good IMHO.

Comment: There are thousands of questions asked on this site every day. It's a miracle that any of us get answers out of that sea.

Comment: Out of the 30 questions I've asked with the least number of views, 12 have been answered. Some of these have ~300 views and still no answer. This is the nature of asking questions on the Internet. It's difficult to get the attention of the people that will be able to help.

Comment: There are frequently [over 7,500 questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuLbt.png) a day on [so]; there are, in truth not even close to that many active users that answer questions (in my experience). If you got 6/15 questions answered without even using a bounty, then that is good going.

Comment: Are you asking why this meta question is downvoted? Probably because people do not find it very useful. You asked a very broad question. Most of your questions look good so it's hard to give you any better advise. You already had 6 questions answered, which is a big success for such a young account.

Comment: In theory, improving the quality of your questions will help attract answerers. Be sure to read the help section on the main site. Especially [ask] and [mcve]. Apply the tips there as best you can and hopefully that will help convince someone to take the time to answer.

Comment: If you know the solution to your question, you can post an answer of your own too.

Comment: This question doesn't look very good. The title is too long, the body is too short. While Meta is no so strict as the main site, we still expect that askers follow the conventions for asking question here, like the title should sumarize the body, include enough details directly into the question body, do not "force" people to look on your profile to find your questions, etc. Note: Including links in Meta questions / answers might will attract attention to them but that might not have the effect that you are looking i.e. instead of getting answers you might get your questions being downvoted.

Comment: Be advised: this meta question may attract attention to your existing questions on SO. That may not be attention that you want. See the [meta affect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: For the most part, your questions on the main site look ok. You usually have code and a description of the problem you are going to solve. One suggestion I have is to make your titles shorter. Summarize the problem with 3 or 4 words instead of writing a complete sentence. I understand this isn't always obvious when you start writing a question. That's why I almost always leave the title for last.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, OK, but I think if I ask questions with short title, most of the users think I asked a general question and so I don't get decent amount of clicks. Don't you think so?

Comment: @neverStop I can't speak for everyone. For me, short titles get my attention and long titles bore me. The extra words needed for a grammatically correct sentence get in the way of quickly understanding what I will expect to find in your question.

Comment: Title should be a short summary of the question. It's what people will search for in Google and it's what will attract views. Longer titles are too specific while short titles are too generic.

Comment: If a short title attracts my attention, then I'll click on the link to read the sentences that give more detail.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363763/sometimes-alarmmanager-not-trigger-if-i-close-my-app-sometimes-it-does-trigger) should have been closed instead of being answered (or at least migrated). The questions not being answered are low quality IMHO.

Comment: @SecurityHound Could you tell me what is the problem with the question that you think should have been closed?

Comment: @neverStop - A question about Java contains no Java code. See your accepted answer for the reason that question should have been closed, improved, and then reopened

Comment: Yes, but I have used this tag coz basically android uses java language, if it is not java so what does it call? By java tag I meant my question is regarding java language that have been used in android studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, your questions are not of good quality. A lot of them have no code examples. The problems are not described in specific language.

You also tagged most of your questions with only [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). None of these questions are related to the Java language, so the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag is pretty useless, as no Java developers will be able to help. Your questions are all Android-specific. However, the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag is used on so many questions that this is also not much help. You should try to add some more specific tags to your questions to attract more attention.

Also, some of your questions have already been asked on Stack Overflow. You should search more on Stack Overflow to see if there is already an answer to your question before you post a question.

Comment: Re: *You should search more on Stackoverflow*. Use a search engine to search for questions on Stack Overflow. The on-site search is pretty much useless.

Comment: Re: I think you should search more in general. Do not post a meta question on SO, because it is "off topic" by essence @neverStop.